# Signing a Microsoft Office Addin MSI

Tags: windows-installer, vsto, ms-office, powerpoint

We have created a PowerPoint addin for a client. The addin will support silent installation through an MSI installer.
As known, the MSI will need to be signed and the certificate should be installed on target machines.

The client wants us to handover the installer and he wants to sign it himself (he wont share the certificate). The problem is that to build the solution I would need the certificate!

Should I simply sign it using any of my (dummy) certificates and hand over the MSI to the client who ca then sign it using his certificate? Is this even valid technically?
Will the new certificate override the one I used during build?

How should we proceed?

Thanks a lot for your interest!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so this got resolved. Apparently, we CAN create an MSI package for an office addin without the need to sign it. I did exactly that and now the client will sign the package himself.

Thanks a lot for the replies :)

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned your client wants the MSI signed with their own certificate, but doesn't want to give you the certificate. What a pain.

This really only leaves you with 2 options:

- You give your client the files to include in the MSI and your client builds the MSI, signing it with their own certificate.
- You build an MSI, give it to your client and ask them to build another MSI (that is signed with their certificate) that installs your MSI. See [How to create a nested .msi package](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306439) for more details.

Another option is to post your question again and include the MSI tag so more MSI developers see your question. They might come up with some more ideas.

**UPDATE**

I've spoken with InstallShield (Flexera Software) today and I asked them about Nested MSI's. They said you shouldn't nest MSI's. So forget that idea.

Comment: I just edited the question to include tags.
Thanks a lot for your response though and special thanks for the nested MSI comment. :)

Any reason why InstallShield advised against it? Or is it simply "bad" ;-)